# jQuery event not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to activate a scrip on click of a checkout button. This checks certain fields are filled in (Delivery type: radiodel1 and 2; Date; and Time) and returns an alert if the user hasn't filled in these fields. This works fine on a desktop browser but on testing on a mobile (iphone) the script doesn't seem to run and the user can just go straight to the checkout page. 
Is there something in my code that won't function on a mobile?

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('a[class="cart-checkout button"]').click(function() {

    if (jQuery('#radiodel1').is(':not(:checked')) {

      if (jQuery('#radiodel2').is(':not(:checked')) {

        alert("Please select delivery type");
        return false;
      } else {

        if (jQuery('#date').val() == '') {
          alert("Please select delivery date");
          return false;
        } else {
          if (jQuery('#time').val() == '0') {
            alert("Please select delivery time");
            return false;
          } else {
            jQuery(this).submit();
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      jQuery(this).submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: On mobile, you don't click, you „tap”. Use a jquery plugin that normalize click and tap or create different handler for each event

Comment: Have you run exactly the same test on both?  I'm not sure I see how this can work on a desktop - the logic seems flawed.  It looks like if `radiodel1` is checked, the form will submit, no matter what else is or is not checked, and even if it's not, there is a case where the form will submit.  Also, I've never had trouble with a jquery `click` function on a mobile device - so I don't think that's where the problem is.

Comment: @sideroxylon - radiodel1 and radiodel2 are two seperate options for delivery: if radiodel1 is selected there is no requirement for the date or time. If radiodel2 is selected then there is. I have tested the functioning of it and it seems to be fine. When trying this same test on a mobile the click function is ignored.

Comment: @cox But this would mean that other click functions would not work - and they do in my case

Comment: Add `console.log('clicked');` immediately after the click function - if it's triggered, then your click function is OK, and the problem is in the logic/nested conditional statement syntax.

Comment: @sideroxylon Thanks - didn't realise you could do this in Safari! The click function was working though. The following expression for some reason wasn't recognised: `is(':not(:checked'))`

Comment: I ended up changing this to `prop('checked') == false)` and it works (on ios at least) and desktop. Any idea why the syntax `is('not(:checked'))` doesn't work on mobile?